# Get Data From Weather JSON Feed

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get the weather from api.openweathermap.org. I can print the wind speed but when I try to print the weather it is giving me an error, but I'm accessing it in the same way as the wind speed. Here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$data = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk');
$json = json_decode($data);
//This works
echo 'The wind speed is: ' . $json->wind->speed;
//This doesn't work
echo 'The weather is: ' . $json->weather->description;
```

This is what happens when I run it:

> The wind speed is: 2.07
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\php-
>   test.php on line 10
>
> The weather is:

Why does it work for the wind speed but not the weather description? The element is present in the json being returned.

Comment: The weather consists of a list of entries; so you need to pick an element from that list first before you can get the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$data = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk');
$json = json_decode($data);

var_dump($json);
echo 'The wind speed is: ' . $json->wind->speed;
//This doesn't work
echo 'The weather is: ' . $json->weather[0]->description;
```

Why your code is error because weather is not object. Weather is an array.

If you `var_dump()` the $json data.It will display the detail. You also can the data for the weather at http://api.openweathermap.org/. The data inside the `[]`. It means this is an array.

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'coord' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'lon' => float -0.13
      public 'lat' => float 51.51
  public 'sys' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'message' => float 0.0166
      public 'country' => string 'GB' (length=2)
      public 'sunrise' => int 1430023268
      public 'sunset' => int 1430075724
  public 'weather' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'id' => int 801
          public 'main' => string 'Clouds' (length=6)
          public 'description' => string 'few clouds' (length=10)
          public 'icon' => string '02n' (length=3)
  public 'base' => string 'stations' (length=8)
  public 'main' => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'temp' => float 282.349
      public 'temp_min' => float 282.349
      public 'temp_max' => float 282.349
      public 'pressure' => float 1013.66
      public 'sea_level' => float 1021.61
      public 'grnd_level' => float 1013.66
      public 'humidity' => int 79
  public 'wind' => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'speed' => float 2.07
      public 'deg' => float 33.0002
  public 'clouds' => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'all' => int 24
  public 'dt' => int 1430076277
  public 'id' => int 2643743
  public 'name' => string 'London' (length=6)
  public 'cod' => int 200
```

Comment: I think we got a winner :)

Answer (score 0):

The weather in the JSON is an array:

```
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 801,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "few clouds",
        "icon": "02d"
    }
],
```

Maybe you could do

```
 echo 'The weather is: ' . $json->weather[0]->description;
```